# How to hide or remove useless network names from the wifi menubar icon

Tags: macos, wifi, software-recommendation

I have obnoxious neighbors that think its funny to use offensive words for their SSIDs.

I would like to remove those SSIDs from, at a minimum, the wifi menubar icon.  If its easier, hiding/removing them from the OS completely (menubar icon and system prefs) would be acceptable.

I'm an OS X newbie, so I don't even know where to start with this.

I prefer built-in solutions (read: free), but solutions < $10.00 would be ok too.

Comment: I would also like to keep this list to something readable when I only have to choose among 4 different wireless networks and not twenty.

Comment: Thanks for the bump, @GrahamPerrin.  I'm still looking for an answer to this one.

Comment: Contexts for the current bounty include http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?p=20841471#post20841471

Comment: I have updated my answer

Comment: See my comment on password on my answer comments. I am still trying to find a work around

Comment: I think it is a better idea to tell them not to be offensive by asking them or changing your SSID to **DontBeOffensive** 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could place something like this Applescript in you **Applescript Menu** and use it to list you preferred networks, choose on and connect to it.

```
set the getList to paragraphs of (do shell script "networksetup -listpreferredwirelessnetworks en0")


    set title to item 1 of getList
    set wifi_list to items 2 thru -1 of getList

   set the chosen_newtwork to choose from list the wifi_list with prompt "Choose a " & title without multiple selections allowed

    if the chosen_newtwork is false then return

    do shell script "networksetup -setairportnetwork en0  " & (chosen_newtwork as string)
```

[image]

(I cannot say this is perfect as I have found it sometimes does not always want to connect but I am unsure if that is just my router/wifi)

---

Update.

Using the same idea above, you could also create a banned list of bad ssids.

And filter them.

The main command is using a **airport** framework command instead of the networksevice command so is a tad slower. But scans for **available** networks instead of just you preferred.

```
    set bannedList to {"BTWifi-X"}
    set wifi_list to {}
    set the getList to paragraphs of (do shell script "/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/airport -s |awk '{print  $1}'")

    set title to item 1 of getList
repeat with i from 2 to number of items in getList
        set this_item to item i of getList
        if this_item is not in bannedList then
            if this_item is not in wifi_list then -- stops duplicates from original list
                copy this_item to end of wifi_list
            end if
        end if
    end repeat

    set the chosen_newtwork to choose from list the wifi_list with prompt "Choose a " & title without multiple selections allowed

    if the chosen_newtwork is false then return

    do shell script "networksetup -setairportnetwork en0  " & (chosen_newtwork as string)
```

Comment: This seems like a perfectly reasonable solution.  I will try it tomorrow and, if it works, accept your answer.

Comment: I tried it in 10.9.5 and it only works limited. It scans and displays the list of all networks, asking me to select one. Then it comes up with it can not connect ? to my network. "Failed to join network rocket.
Error: -3905  Timeout error" and then it stays disconnected until I stop the script.

Comment: @buscar Similar to what I was getting on 10.10.x  but I did get some connections.  the code is standard code to do the connection. But I will look to see if i have missed an option

Comment: @Buscar found the problem. If you connect to a wifi that does not have a password, no problem. But if it does you need to add the password onto the end of the command ` networksetup -setairportnetwork en0   'myNet'  'my password'`  I do not have any easy way yet of getting the password without having to type your admin password..

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you can directly filter SSIDs from that list. However there are a couple ways to hide the Wifi icon from the bar.

Click on the icon -> "Open network preferences" --> Bottom of that window is a checkbox. "Show Wifi Status in Menu Bar".

The other option, would be to use an application like Bartender. It cost money, but will let you hide/rearrange the top bar.

If you're just trying to hide the dialog from your children, then those two options should be good enough.

Comment: I really appreciate the suggestions!  However, I don't want to remove the entire icon, just the offending menu items.  The icon menu is very useful to me.. but I'm tired of seeing "GO F*** YOURSELF!" every time I click on it.

Comment: Because my work often requires me to switch networks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the best option would be to create an Automator/AppleScript to join each of the networks you have to jump between.

You could create your own Application or Service for the networks you use often, and use your System Preference pane for when you are in a different location and need to join Wifi.

Depending on your scripting ability, you could use one Workflow/Script with some logic to toggle between networks based on which one you're currently connected to.

Comment: This answer could be a good for a different question, but it does not answer the essence of this question. The essence here is a wish to **hide or remove the name of a network**.

Comment: I understand your position, but disagree; I think the goal of the asker is to avoid seeing the SSIDs which are offensive.  While this may not accomplish this 100% of the time, it can significantly reduce the issue.