# How do I prevent my mac's wifi from ever (not just once) seeing a particular wifi network?

Tags: network, wifi, password

So here is my dilemma- I'm addicted to the internet and I don't want to have the option of using it in my home except for particular times.

On my own network, I plan to change the password to something long and unmemorizable and write it down and leave it somewhere else (say the coffee shop) /tell it to a friend etc so that I can have the option of using it- then tell my key chain to forget the network's password. Problem solved!

The only issue is that my upstairs neighbors have a network and I know the password! If only I could delete it from the keychain in my head, but I can't. I can ask them to change the password, and will, but it's not their problem and I feel silly doing so. Plus even if they do it'll take them forever..

So my question is: Is there a way to prevent my computer from using a particular network, forever - so that my computer sees it and automatically ignores it?

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: you could just use parental controls and have a friend set the password.

Comment: [How to hide or remove certain SSIDs from the wifi menubar icon](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/128445/8546) (2014-04-23) – the bounty there might attract an answer that could be helpful here.

Answer (score 2):

What about something even easier? There's a great app for OS X called [Concentrate](http://www.getconcentrating.com/) that will block distractions for you for periods of time. In particular it'll block your access to apps when you want to focus so you can stop surfing Ask Different when you should be studying. Have it block Chrome, Safari and Firefox and any other apps you find distracting and you might find that's easier than trying to have WiFi but not have your computer connect to it.

Answer (score 0):

Go to System Preferences > Network, and click on Advanced. Go to the Wi-Fi tab (if you're not there by default), scroll through the list of networks until you find the one you want to forget, select it, and then click the minus sign at the lower left of the list of networks.