# Filter out some WiFi networks from list of all available WiFi networks

Tags: network, wifi

Is it possible to filter out some WiFi networks from list of all available WiFi networks when I drop down the WiFi list from the menu bar in macOS?

My condo complex has a lot of networks and it clutters the list. I only ever need 3 -- my home  WiFi, my work WiFi, my iPhone WiFi.

Comment: I know Windows 10 has this ability, but I haven't found it for macOS (yet).  However, that said, once you remember the network, you shouldn't have to keep getting a list of all the broadcast SSIDs.  What exactly is happening that you're looking for this particular solution?

Comment: Here is  a possible answer https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/177182/46541